# How to send MultiPart HTTP request using Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring, http, rest, spring-mvc, post

I am new to Spring framework and i am learning.

My web applicaiton based out of Spring MVC needs to call a vendor service through RESTful interface.

I have current implementation for POST / GET for non multipart.
However i have a requirement to POST multipart form data consisting of JSON and Bytes

I am trying to see some smaple implementation online for reference but could not get one.

I need some idea about possible approach i can take to implement this using RestTemplate.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What research have you done? What have you found? Don't tell us _nothing_, because there are tons of examples of this online.

Comment: _http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html is the one i am currently going through.

Comment: To be frank i was also not sure what is the right way to do it as i have a deep thought that i might not be going in right direction since i am new to the framework.

Comment: Above all, if you know please provide online reference if not may be someone would help me out. I am not here spending time to ask something i know. It takes good time amount of time to ask a question. It just not the laziness we are posting question.

Comment: Spring is currently at major version 4. Have you read the javadoc of RestTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

if we want to send multipart form data in post request and with that if you also want some information in json format then you can create your REST call according to this. here @Consumes will say that this call will accept only MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, @Transactional is for starting new transaction.

Here i am accepting three path parameters which are

1) String jsonObj, this is a string or you can say json, in this JSON you can ask UI for required information like some tags, labels, etc

2) FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail, This will contain very basic detail of file, like fileName, contentType, etc

3) InputStream uploadedInputStream, this will contain some binary data, like image, videos, or any kind of files in byte format.

*** Example ***

```
@POST

@Path("/xyz")

@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)

public VObject postMultiPartFormData(

           @FormDataParam("jsonObj") String jsonObj,

           @FormDataParam("mmFile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,

           @FormDataParam("mmFile") InputStream uploadedInputStream) {

    return new VObject();
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: But i am looking for reference to call a RESTful client not to handle the POST request from View into the Controller. still trying to understand how to make a Multipart POST request